# Call mysql Database remotely from another network

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I am new to MySQL database.

I have tried remote database calling with in the network. It is working but I would like to know can we do this if the remote call is from different network (i.e: for example database host server public IP address is 115.122.133.89 and the caller application public IP address  is 115.122.134.63).

Application is gonna run in windows and database server will be installed in Linux (CENTOS)

If can may I know how to do this.

Comment: Hey Rajesh, I think this question is a better fit for Serverfault.  I wouldn't anticipate problems with Go (or any language really) connecting to a database on a remote system.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would start with the basics for this. Can you establish a connection to your DB server from you app server? using a command like netcat should be able to tell you this `nc -z $DB_SERVER_IP 3306`.

Once you have established that the connection is indeed working, getting the same DB connection to [work from Go](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#usage) should be a matter connecting via the DSN